# Watershed layers with names for each one for Europe or Sweden?

Tags: data, watershed, europe, layer-resource, sweden

I am working on freshwater species and I would like, make a list of each watersheds used for each species.

So I am looking for a watershed maps which contain name of the watershed.

I found some good layers, but, they don't get names for each basins, only for the bigger ones.

I would like to know if someone can give me advices, links or good sources?

I need mainly the cover for Sweden at least, or Europe.

I searched this site, but I found most of the elements to create watersheds.

Answer (score 2):

Please check out http://data.freshwaterbiodiversity.eu/shapefiles/ it may help. This contains lot of shape files for research.

Answer (score 1):

The [Catchment Characterisation and Modelling (CCM)](http://ccm.jrc.ec.europa.eu/php/index.php?action=view&id=23) site has European wide catchment data.

You can download the river networks and watershed boundaries.